# JSF Primefaces Bean: How to delete selected value from SelectOneListBox?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a selectOneListBox with some data. After selecting a value and a click on the REMOVE button, the value has to be removed. I need to do this in my Bean. I think the problem is in the if-Statement or in `codeValue`

**My xhtml:**

```
  <p:selectOneListbox id="list" value="#{codelistBean.codeValue2}"                  style="height:300px;overflow:scroll;margin:1px;width:250px"
    autoUpdate="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{codelistBean.code2Value}" />
    </p:selectOneListbox>`
```

**My Bean:**

**Variables**

```
String codeValue;

 private static Map<String, Object> codeValue = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
```

Here I'm putting some values to the Map:

```
codeValue.put(getLabel(), getValue());
```

**the remove Method**

```
public void removeCode(ActionEvent e) {

        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = codeValue.entrySet()
                .iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

            Entry<String, Object> entry2 = it.next();

            if (entry2.getKey().equals(codeValue.get(codeValue2))) {
                it.remove();

            }
        }

    }
```

Finally I'm returning the Map to JSF to display it

```
public Map<String, Object> getCode2Value() {
        return codeValue;
    }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: As explained in the comment of my deleted answer about the wrong `==` vs `equals()` usage, the cause of your concrete problem is elsewhere, not visible in the code provided so far (assuming that the `it.remove()` line is *really* executed as you seem to be implying). You was also asked to come up with an SSCCE, but you didn't. How are we supposed to help you? Help us to help you! To learn how to create a proper SSCCE for JSF, read the introduction of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Angry? I just wanted to help you out with this problem. Why don't you help us to help you? If I was angry, I wouldn't have attempted to help you in any way, but just ignored you altogether :)

Comment: Ok, well, I don't know exactly what a SSCCE is. I have tried to explain the code more and added some lines. Thanks

Comment: Click the link in my 1st comment for the explanation of SSCCE. It's basically a very minimal but still complete example which others (like me) could just copy'n'paste'n'run into a blank test environment to see your concrete problem without the need to add some unobvious code. The currently edited code is still not a real SSCCE. The cause of the problem is not visible in there. You're for example not showing how you're invoking the action and presenting the results. Also, you didn't exactly describe the problem symptoms (but I'll assume that the changes aren't been reflected in the view side).

Comment: well, this code will probably end up in compilation error because of your `String codeValue` and `private static Map<String, Object> codeValue`. The main goals of the SSCCE are explained here: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @akoskm: this part is indeed strange, but it should just compile fine. The `equals()` method just takes `Object`.

Comment: @BalusC I mean it will end up in compilation error because `codeValue` is already defined with `String codeValue;` (Variables part), breaking the "Correct" rule of the SSCCE.

Comment: regarding your original problem, this code probably runs fine if the string representation of your labels and values is the same for every key/values pair... so the problem is not explicitly in your if statement. I would suggest using List<SelectItem> instead of HashMap. It provides a clean, straightforward implementation.

Comment: @Johnny2012 have you tried the alternative implementation behind selectOneListbox like I described in my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a static HashMap, you can define a list of `SelectItem`s:

```
String codeValue2;
List<SelectItem> codeValue = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

//getters & setters
```

it holds key/value pairs just as your HashMap, the only difference is the value/label order:

```
codeValue.add(new SelectItem(value,label))
```

The remove function can be simplified:

```
   public void removeCode(ActionEvent e) {

       SelectItem remove = null;
       for (SelectItem item : codeValue) {
           if (item.getValue().equals(codeValue2)) {
               remove = item;
           }
       }
       codeValue.remove(remove);
    }
```

Note that you can also remove the `ActionEvent e` parameters from your method header, it is not required.

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="list" value="#{codelistBean.codeValue2}"
                    style="height:300px;overflow:scroll;margin:1px;width:250px"
                    autoUpdate="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{codelistBean.codeValue}" />
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

On your jsf page the `f:selectItems value="#{codelistBean.codeValue}"` points to the `List<SelectItem>` while `value="#{codelistBean.codeValue2}"` is representing the actual selection.

Finally, don't forget to update your `list` after executing the REMOVE button:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{codeListBean.removeCode}" 
                 value="REMOVE" update="list"/>
```